# *Why* Does the SQL Server Debugger Require Sysadmin Privileges

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I recently posted a question looking to [find an alternative to granting devs `sysadmin` privileges just to use the sql server debugger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188348/sql-server-debugger-permissions-without-granting-sysadmin-to-devs). I am finding that there really isn't a feasible solution to this.

My question here is, ***WHY* does the sql server debugger require sysadmin privileges?** I want to understand the reasons behind designing it this way.

In a dev environment, developers should be able to do dev activities such as using the built-in debugger tools without granting sysadmin, instead of being told to basically build his own debugging mechanism using print statements, etc.

SQL server has privileges for so many specific roles/tasks, etc, it's odd not to see a separate one for this e.g. which could be granted only in a dev environment, etc.

I don't think this question is a duplicate of the others, since this question is not about *how* to use the debugger if you aren't a sysadmin, but rather, it is so I can understand *why it is designed this way*.

Comment: Why don’t you grant sysadmin to developers in dev environments anyway?

Comment: I haven't seen definitive evidence for this, but I presume it is because performing debugging steps on a database can cause serious issues with contention and blocking to the point where it shouldn't be a feature that is easy to doll out access to. It seems [MS doesn't plan on changing this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/674589/t-sql-debugging-only-with-sa-privileges), either.

Comment: If you have developers use local copies instead of a shared instance, @MartinSmith 's suggestion is even less for you to worry about.

Comment: @MartinSmith - in this case, I am the developer, not the DBA. Just want to be sure I understand the whole thing before I have discussions. Company policy where i am working is to not ever grant sysadmin to users in any environment.

Comment: @LowlyDBA - Local copies isn't really feasible either. Huge multiple-db system which many distributed systems also interact with, hence the need for centrally managed environments for end-to-end dev/test/uat, etc.  But again, I am not looking for a solution in this question - just for some background info on why it is set up this way. I think you have provided that.